# Adding Description/Metadata to Azure Blob

Tags: azure, blob, metadata

I couldn't find this from Microsoft support page,
but Is it possible to add description/metadata to an Azure Blob using Azure Portal? Without using any lines of code.

Comment: At this time you can't do it in Azure portal but there are many storage explorers (including a free one from Microsoft - http://storageexplorer.com), that you can use for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer to do it. 
http://storageexplorer.com/releasenotes.html

It allows you to edit metadata graphically like so:

[image: Adding metadata to a blob with Storage Explorer]