# How to add and retrive additional information for Azure Blob

Tags: c#, .net, azure, blob, azure-storage

Is there a way to add additional information for blob in Azure?

I want to store some relevant information, which connects the blob to other entity in in an a document database, for example a string which contains a JSON.

I know there is metadata for blob when I use Azure Storage explorer, but i want use it from code.

This a relevant question about this theme:
[Adding Description/Metadata to Azure Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965474/adding-description-metadata-to-azure-blob)

And how can retrieve the blobs based on this metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of the question is answered by Mihail Stancescu, thank you!

The second part is not answered correctly yet. The Azure Search is a solution for it, but it is a totally other service.  I want to solve this problem in my repository class. And i solved it.

Maybe it is interesting for someone else that is why I share my solution:

**Behind the solution**
There is a metadata in AzureBlob, which has a string type. I serialized a object to String and store this string in metadata. When I need this information in any cases, I listing the with metadata in it. I reach this this functionality to passing the *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobListingDetails.Metadata* value to the *blobListingDetails* parameter in *ListBlobs* function.

When The blobs are arrived, I inmediatly Deserialized back from JSON to object. This mechasim is visible in LINQ Select:

```
.Select<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob, T>(blob = > JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(blob.Metadata["data"]))
```

After this, the LINQ type is T, so I can Apply the Expression on it in LINQ Where.

The complete solution is:

**GetMany function**

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetMany( Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter )
{
            return _AzureBlobCollection.BlobDirectory
                .ListBlobs( useFlatBlobListing: false, blobListingDetails: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobListingDetails.Metadata )
                .OfType<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob>()
                .Select<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob, T>( blob => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>( blob.Metadata[ "data" ] ) )
                .Where( filter.Compile() );
}
```

This function can call like this:
    Repository repository = ..

```
IEnumerable files = repository.GetMany( f => f.Partner = "Microsoft" );
```

**Base classes**

where file class is:

```
public class ContractFile : File
{
    public string Partner { get; set; }
    public Date CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
...
public class File
{
    public String File { get; set; }
    public Stream Data { get; set; }
}
```

And the insert is following:

```
    public void AddOne( T file )
    {
        file.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob blob = _AzureBlobCollection.BlobDirectory.GetBlockBlobReference( file.id );

        blob.UploadFromStream( file.Data );
        blob.Metadata.Add( "data", JsonConvert.SerializeObject( file ) );
        blob.SetMetadata();
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why is this answer is downvoted. Please leave a comment about your problem, and I will correct it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-properties-metadata)?

```
public static async Task AddContainerMetadataAsync(CloudBlobContainer container)
{
   // Add some metadata to the container.
   container.Metadata.Add("docType", "textDocuments");
   container.Metadata["category"] = "guidance";

   // Set the container's metadata.
   await container.SetMetadataAsync();
}
```

Keep in mind that

> The name of your metadata must conform to the naming conventions for C# identifiers.

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to listing this blobs based on metadata content?

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-blob-storage-integration?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json#search-through-your-blob-metadata). I haven't tried it yet. I usually get them by the default index and then display the metadata.